# Multiple Choice Option Cells in Python Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'd like to create a multiple choice menu within a **.ipynb** that determines what upcoming cell shows up. For example, I want to insert a question and have someone viewing the notebook be able to pick:

⦿ Choice A

⦿ Choice B

If the user picks A, a cell shows up. If the user picks B, a different cell shows up next.

Comment: this seems relevant : https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/2487